# How to import large csv file(400mb approx) in jupyter notebook using python?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, python-3.7

Already tried this code:

```
import pandas as pd
a="C://concatenated_csv.csv"
df=pd.read_csv(a, header=None, sep='\t', iterator=True, chunksize=2000000)
print (df)
```

but I get the following error:

```
pandas.io.parsers.TextFileReader object at 0x07CF1310
```

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: <pandas.io.parsers.TextFileReader object at 0x07CF1310>